# Using shadow on mat-card in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, shadow

I am working on a project with an angular frontend and I am trying to add a shadow to one of my components and have read that `class="mat-elevation-z8"` should do the trick. However, it does not do anything.

My html :

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title *ngIf="message">{{(message.title | truncateword: 25) | slice:0:30}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle *ngIf="message">{{message.publishedAt | date}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>

  <img *ngIf="image" [src]="image" alt="Here might be a preview image" mat-card-image>

    <mat-card-content>
      <p *ngIf="message">
        {{(message.summary | truncateword:70 | slice:0:73)}}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Also, I am importing `~@angular/material/theming` in my styles.css, so that should not be the problem either. Here is the styles in my angular.json:

```
 "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try on :

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Comment: It's deprecated to use `@import`. Use `angular.json`'s scripts part instead.

Comment: can you explain that ?

Comment: I meant styles part, not scripts part. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles#global-styles explains how to correctly import styles in Angular. When you use @import you actually get a warning about the deprecation in your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I am already importing deeppurple-amber.css. I have updated the question

Comment: This is tutorial example on the Angular Material page [angular-material-card-shadow](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-card-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Angular material mat card shadow can be toggled using [class.mat-elevation-z8] attribute

```
<mat-card [class.mat-elevation-z8]="false">
   Example
</mat-card>
```